# Django GenericForeignKey being deleted when it shouldn't

Tags: python, django, generic-foreign-key

I'm having a problem where if I delete an object, another object is being deleted seemingly wrongly.

**models.py**

```py
class Document(models.model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=document_path, null=True, max_length=256)
    ri_ct = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, null=True, editable=False, related_name='documents_related_item', on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    ri_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, editable=False, db_index=True)
    related_item = GenericForeignKey('ri_ct', 'ri_id')


class Invoice(models.model):
    documents = GenericRelation(
        Document, related_query_name='invoices', content_type_field='ri_ct', object_id_field='ri_id'
    )


class BalanceUpdate(models.model):
    related_item_ct = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        limit_choices_to=Q(app_label='main', model__in=('proformainvoice', 'invoice')),
        related_name='balance_updates',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    related_item_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    related_item = GenericForeignKey(ct_field='related_item_ct', fk_field='related_item_id')
```

Now, if I do

```py
Invoice.objects.filter(query).delete()
```

I'm getting a BalanceUpdate, which is related to Invoice, also deleted.

After a fair amount of debugging I've found that when deleting the Invoice, the document is being deleted ([correctly due to the defined GenericRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations)).

If we look at [Collector.collect](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.8/django/db/models/deletion.py#L169) we have a recursive function which collects the objects to be deleted.

If I insert a print [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.8/django/db/models/deletion.py#L228), when the model is Document, sub_objs contains the BalanceUpdate object. How can this be the case? The Document obj surely should have sub_objs containing a BalanceUpdate, they are seemingly not linked?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: It is probably the `on_delete=` trigger of the `GenericForeignKey`?

Comment: As is specified in the documentation "*Unlike ForeignKey, GenericForeignKey does not accept an on_delete argument to customize this behavior; if desired, you can avoid the cascade-deletion by not using GenericRelation, and alternate behavior can be provided via the pre_delete signal.*".

Comment: Right, so deleting the Invoice should delete the Document, (as there is a GenericRelation defined) but should not delete the BalanceUpdate.